# why the image for notification icon generated using Android Asset Studio is completely white?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asset-studio

so I want to make icon for push notification. say for example I want to use the android image below as notification icon

https://p7.hiclipart.com/preview/135/689/279/android-computer-icons-logo-android.jpg

so I try to make it using Android asset studio. but the image generated from this Android Asset studio is completely white like this

[image]

what should I do ? is there any image requirement for this ?

Comment: Any solutions? I have the same issue

Comment: @ДмитроЯковлєв yeah I solve it, but unfortunately I forget, as far as I remember, the issue is in the image itself. I change the image then it solves my problem. I change the image using png format with transparent background

Answer (score 3):

## Use Transparent Images

- The icons generated will be totally solid color (dark grey or white will be used on the device depending on theme).
- The icon you add should only contain the "shape" you want to show as the single color. The rest should be transparent pixels.
- Any non-transparent pixels will be converted to white. So if you have a square logo with no transparent pixels, it will be a giant single colored square.
- Use a .png image so you can save it with transparent background.

Answer (score -2):

As you can see, icons in notifications bar are white, that's why you are seeing all white

[image: nav bar]